# Can't add multiple methods to $firebaseObject via $extend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've been working on combining my flattened data, but when i'm extending my $firebaseObject service I have some really strange behavior. I use a factory to return user data, for example the full name, which works fine. But when i try to add a 2nd Method i can't access the this command.

My factory:

```
// user factory
app.factory("User", ["$firebaseObject", "$firebaseRef",
    function($firebaseObject, $firebaseRef) {
        // create a new service based on $firebaseObject
        var User = $firebaseObject.$extend({
            // these methods exist on the prototype, so we can access the data using `this`
            getTeamName: function() {
                console.log("this: " + this); // Logs: this: [object Object]
                console.log("full name: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName); // Logs: full name: undefined undefined
                console.log("this.teams: " + this.teams); //Logs: this.teams: undefined

                var teamKey = this.teams.$value; // TypeError: Cannot read property '$value' of undefined
                console.log("teamKey: " + teamKey);

                var teamObj = $firebaseObject($firebaseRef.teams.child(teamKey));
                console.log("teamObj.teamName: " + teamObj.teamName);
            },
            getFullName: function() { // Runs just fine
                return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
            }
        });
        return function(uid) {
            // create an instance of User (the new operator is required)
            return new User($firebaseRef.users.child(uid));
        }
    }
]);
```

The strange thing is that getFullName works just fine, any sugjestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `getTeamName` doesn't return anything

Comment: I did not return any thing to bug test, but when i replace 'console.log("teamObj.teamName: " + teamObj.teamName);'  with 'return teamObj.teamName' It gives me teh same errors, "this" is still undifined